# Why are my boolean outputs behaving this way?

Tags: bash

Essentially, I want to say:

```bsh
if [ X1 ] || [ X2 ]
then
    e1 && a && b && e2
else
    e3
done
```

But when X1 and X2 are FALSE, e1, a, b, AND e2 run anyway.  If X1 and X2 are true, the same thing happens.  My booleans are behaving very oddly and I don't understand why...

I have the following code:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

#Define local variables
REPLACING="\033[01;31mReplacing outdated .tex and .json in git repository.\033[0;38m"
COMPLETED="\033[1;38;5;2mTransfer complete.\033[0;38m"
ALL_GOOD="\033[1;38;5;2mYour git repository's templates directory is up to date with your local templates directory connected to TeXStudio IDE.\033[0;38m"

CURRENT_DIR="/Users/jakeireland/Documents/my_macros"

LOCAL_DIR="/Users/jakeireland/.config/texstudio/templates/user/"
GIT_DIR="${CURRENT_DIR}/tea_templates/"

TEX_OLD="${GIT_DIR}*.tex"
JSON_OLD="${GIT_DIR}*.json"

TEX_NEW="${LOCAL_DIR}*.tex"
JSON_NEW="${LOCAL_DIR}*.json"

#Functions to determine congruence of local versus git dir
#cmp -s /path/to/outdated/dir path/to/up-to-date/dir
TEX_CLEAN=$(cmp -s "${TEX_OLD}" "${TEX_NEW}" || echo "tex-err")
JSON_CLEAN=$(cmp -s "${JSON_OLD}" "${JSON_NEW}" || echo "json-err")

#Define functions to copy new files to old directory
#cp -fr /source/file /destination/path
CP_TEX=$(cp -fr ${TEX_NEW} ${GIT_DIR})
CP_JSON=$(cp -fr ${JSON_NEW} ${GIT_DIR})

#Begin script

cd "${CURRENT_DIR}"
if [[ "$TEX_CLEAN" = "tex-err" ]] || [[ "$JSON_CLEAN" = "json-err" ]] ; then 
    echo -e "${REPLACING}" && $CP_TEX && $CP_JSON && echo -e "${COMPLETED}"
else 
    echo -e "${ALL_GOOD}"
fi
```

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: BTW, where you write "define functions", that's not at all what you've done.  Those are variable assignments using *command substitution*.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I have edited my post, thank you. 
As I say, I am very new to bash.  If I have a `longstring`, how to I make a variable so that I don't have to write it out each time?

Comment: `JSON_CLEAN=$(cmp -s "${JSON_OLD}" "${JSON_NEW}" || echo "tex-err")` ... was that supposed to be `json-err`?

Comment: @muru Yes it was sorry.  Have edited my code, but the error still persist

Comment: Other problems: `TEX_OLD="${GIT_DIR}*.tex"` ... `*` won't be expanded when quoted (e.g., in `cmp -s "${TEX_OLD}"`). Run your script with `bash -x` to debug it.

Comment: Thank you @muru.  I've changed this.  The error still persists.  This is likely a stupid question, but why do I need to 'debug it'?

Comment: Well, your program is not working as intended, so it's buggy. So you debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken about where the problem lies.  If you run your program with tracing enabled (e.g. `bash -x the_script`), then you'll see what happens.

These lines do not define functions:

```
#Define functions to copy new files to old directory
CP_TEX=$(cp -fr ${TEX_NEW} ${GIT_DIR})
CP_JSON=$(cp -fr ${JSON_NEW} ${GIT_DIR})
```

What's happening here is that we're running the commands and assigning the output to those variables `CP_TEX` and `CP_JSON`.

If you really meant to define functions, then you would write:

```
cp_tex() {
   cp -fr ${TEX_NEW} ${GIT_DIR}
}
cp_json() {
    cp -fr ${JSON_NEW} ${GIT_DIR}
}
```

However, for a single use, there's little need to define functions.  I'd just write them inline, like this:

```
cd "${CURRENT_DIR}" || exit $?  # remember that `cd` can fail
if cmp -s "${TEX_OLD}" "${TEX_NEW}" || cmp -s "${JSON_OLD}" "${JSON_NEW}"
then
    echo -e "${ALL_GOOD}"
else
    echo -e "${REPLACING}"
    cp -fr "${TEX_NEW}" "${JSON_NEW}" "${GIT_DIR}"
    echo -e "${COMPLETED}"
fi
```

This is all assuming that you really are working with a file called `*.tex` and one called `*.json`, of course.  If you meant those to be wildcards, you'd need to write a loop rather than a simple `cmp` command.

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight.  I have tried previously to use that structure to define my functions, but it doesn't seem to work.  When I change my code to match the style in your answer, there is no error, but it does not register that I have changed anything.

Comment: Have you read and understood the relevant parts of the Bash manual?  Without that, you'll find yourself floundering in the dark.  You can't learn a programming language by trial and error!

Comment: Perhaps start with something simpler (`if true || false; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi`) and build up from there, rather than taking on everything at once?

Comment: Yes, I have read the relevant parts of the manual, and I have created basic scripts.  I have made [this](https://pastebin.com/qSz8N0yg) so I am not entirely useless.  I do appreciate your help though, so thank you ever so much :-)

Comment: @ChristopherTatlock you should look up [`case` statements in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case).

Comment: Thank you @muru, I will look into this.  Thank you for your help